# Why javascript locks occurs when we are performing Map & Reduce operations?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Map Reduce uses custom JavaScript functions to perform the map & reduce operations.There is a JavaScript lock. Mongodb server can only execute one JavaScript function at a point in time.so locks can be yielded frequently..so I want to know why Mongodb server can execute one JavaScript function at one point?What's the reason behind these JavaScript locks during Map & Reduce opeartions?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is Asynchronous, not multithreaded... unless you have multiple processes in NodeJS.
JavaScript is driven by an event loop. Give that a little exploration and maybe start looking into having multiple node processes running.

Docker containers is a good way to get multiple nodejs processes going in a exactly mirror environment. It may take some learning, and I wish you luck.